# In Spark Streaming (PySpark), how do I stop after it has finished streaming over RDD once?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am using the following code snippet to train Streaming K-Means. Is it possible to stop the streaming context when it has finished streaming over the `rdd` **once**? How do I know if it has finished going over RDD completely?

```py
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
streamingKMeansModel = StreamingKMeans(k=k, decayFactor=1.0).setInitialCenters(init_centers, [1.0] * len(init_centers))
streamingKMeansModel.trainOn(ssc.queueStream([rdd]))
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(timeout=30*60)

# What I want:

if processed_the_rdd_once:
    ssc.stop()
```

From another forum, I got the following answer: "I think you can attach a listener that can shutdown if it detects the end of stream". Is there an example code for this in **pyspark**?

Comment: Is there a reason to use StreamingKMeans instead of KMeans on a batch dataset? What's the need of streaming if you want to stop after the first iteration?

Comment: @maasg Yeah, I want to obtain results from this variant of the algorithm for comparison purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I contributed a possible answer for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the Streaming job right after it has processed the first RDD of a `QueueDStream`, it should be sufficient to schedule a `stop` right after the training operation. We can do that using the general-purpose `foreachRDD`. The lambda provided will be scheduled sequentially after the `trainOn` call ([which is a `foreachRDD` call on its own](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/StreamingKMeans.scala#L271))

Something like this should do the trick:

```
...
dstream = ssc.queueStream([rdd])
streamingKMeansModel.trainOn(dstream)

dstream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: ssc.stop(false)) 
    #stop(false) lets the underlying spark context active, so that we can use the trained model further on.

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(timeout=30*60)
```